Reflection of the "Figure Eight" not diffeomorphic to the "Figure Eight"
In problem 3 of page 73 from "An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry" by Boothby, he defines the "figure eight" as:
$G(t) = \left( \left( 2\cos(g(t) - \frac{\pi}{2} \right), \sin(2(g(t)-\frac{\pi}{2})\right)$
Where $g(t)$ is a monotonic increasing function such that: $g(0) = \pi,\; lim_{x\to+\infty}, \; g(t)=2\pi,\; lim_{x\to-\infty} g(t)= 0$.
Based on that the aim is to show that the reflection $H(x^1,x^2) \to (x^1,-x^2)$ is not a diffeomorphism onto the imagine $N$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Where the topology and $C^{\infty}$ structure is given by $G(t)$.
My idea
Since $G(t)$ is giving the topology for both its image and the reflection under $H$, then if I take the an open set $U \subset N$ such that $G^{-1}(U) \subset (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} )$ then $U$ is open in $N$, but when I consider $G^{-1} \circ H(U)$  then $-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ become limit points of my set, so $G^{-1} \circ H(U)$ will be closed, so that $H$ cannot be a homeomorphism.
My question is this idea is right? And if so how can I use the information I have to formalize the idea, is there any other way to show that $H$ is not a diffeomorphism?

It is not clear what you ask. Do you ask whether $H(N) = N$ with $N = G(\mathbb R)$?

Yes, I'm trying to show that the reflection $H(N)$ is not a homeomorphism given that the topological structure is given by $G(t)$.

Still not clear. Perhaps you mean that the bijection $\mathbb R \xrightarrow{G} N \xrightarrow{H}N \xrightarrow{G^{-1}} \mathbb R$ is no diffeomorphism? If so, edit your question.

No, the question on the book states that $H(x^1,x^2) \to (x^1,-x^2)$, despite being a map of $N$ onto $N$ is not diffeomorphism of $N$.  Is that the same as what you're saying?

A look into Boothby's book shows that he uses the concept of an imnmersed submanifold (see Definition 4.3).
$N = G( \mathbb R)$ is regarded as such an object. This means that $N$ is not regarded as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ (which would be the usual interpretation), but is endowed with the (unique!) topology and $C^\infty$-structure which makes $G : \mathbb R \to N$ a diffeomorphism.
With this interpretation  $N$ is a $C^\infty$-manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, but it is not a submanfold of $\mathbb R^2$. Actually the subspace $N \subset \mathbb R^2$ does not admit any $C^\infty$-structure  (the "self-intersection" at $(0,0)$ prevents this).

Is $H : N \to N, H(x,y) = (x,-y)$, a diffeomorphism?

The answer is "no". Actually it is not even continuous. This may be surprising at first glance because $H : \mathbb R^2 \to  \mathbb R^2$ is a homeomorphism, so one might expect that the restriction $H : N \to N$ also is one. But recall that $N$ is not regarded as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.
Your idea was in fact right, but I think it was not properly elaborated.
With the above interpretation of $N$, the map $G :  N \to N$ is a diffeomorphism, thus the above question is equivalent to

Is $\bar H : \mathbb R \xrightarrow{G} N \xrightarrow{H} N \xrightarrow{G^{-1}} \mathbb R$ a diffeomorphism?

Note that $H^{-1} = H$ and $\bar H^{-1} = \bar H$. Boothby's definition of $G$ (based on changing parameter via $g$) has the property that $G(0) = (0,0)$. Let $N_{\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y} = \{ (x,y) \in N \mid \epsilon_x x > 0, \epsilon_y y > 0 \}$, where $\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y$ take the values $\pm 1$. These sets are the intersections of $N$ with the four open quadrants of the plane.
Let $R_+ > 0$ and $R_- < 0$ be the points with $G(R_+) = (2,0)$ and $G(R_-) = (-2,0)$. Then $G((0,R_+)) = N_{+1,-1}$, $G((R_+,\infty)) = N_{+1,+1}$, $G((R_-,0)) = N_{-1,+1}$, $G((-\infty,R_-)) = N_{-1,-1}$.
Since $H(N_{\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y}) = N_{\epsilon_x,-\epsilon_y}$, we get
$$\bar H^{-1}((R_-,R_+)) = \bar H((R_-,R_+)) = \bar H((R_-,0) \cup \{0\} \cup (0,R_+)) \\=  \bar H((R_-,0)) \cup \bar H(\{0\}) \cup \bar H((0,R_+)) = (-\infty,R_-) \cup \{0\} \cup (R_+,\infty)$$
which is not open in $\mathbb R$. Thus $\bar H$ is not continuous.

@Martin You are right, I made a mistake (which I corrected). The points $(\pm 2,0)$ lie on $N$. Recall that $G$ was defined as $G(t) = F(g(t))$ with $F(t) = \left( 2\cos(t - \frac{\pi}{2}), \sin(2(t-\frac{\pi}{2})\right)$. We have $F(0) = F(\pi) = F(2\pi) =(0,0)$, $F(\frac{\pi}{2}) = (2,0)$ and $F(\frac{3\pi}{2}) = (-2,0)$.
